# How to list all author's names at reference section using natbib package?

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to list all the author's names (even more than 7) at the References section instead of the default "et al".

I'm using a journal template which uses the natbib package. I have tried "maxbibname" but it always gives the following compile error:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.
> The package natbib has already been loaded with options:
> [numbers]
> There has now been an attempt to load it with options
> [numbers,maxbibnames =8]
> Adding the global options:
> numbers,numbers,maxbibnames =8
> to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

The initial commands I'm using are:

```
\documentclass{wiley-article}
\usepackage[numbers,maxbibnames =8]{natbib}
```

I understand that there must be some predefined settings on the overleaf template, but how to override them?

Comment: `natbib` doesn't provide a `maxbibnames` option, actually. You may want to double-check with the journal you're submitting to, that they _require_ all authors to be listed, before trying to modify how the template or bibliography style behaves.

Comment: They returned my submission saying that et al. is not acceptable at references section!! Thanks for stopping by @LianTzeLim .

Answer (score 0):

Using the [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wiley-journal-template/nnjcnfyhzcqp) on Overleaf you can get the full author list with

```
\documentclass{wiley-article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Comment: Doing so generates the following error: **BibTeX Illegal, another \bibstyle command : \bibstyle : {unsrtnat}** Thanks @luki

Comment: Somewhere another bibstyle is loaded. Could you please post a minimal complete example which produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue by modifying the Wiley-article.cls

The original code:

```
  \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{vancouver-authoryear}
```

The modifications:

```
  \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```